# Codeigniter 3x Query Builder class seems to be generating extra segments to my query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using the latest version of the Codeigniter framework for PHP. Here is my code.

```
public function get_user_by_username( $username ) {

    $this->db->where( 'username', strtolower( $username ) );
    $q = $this->db->get( 'users', 1 );

    foreach( $q->result() as $row ) {

        return $row;
    }

    return NULL
}
```

I called the **last_query()** method to get the query that was generating the problem and this pops up messing up the entire query. I didn't code this. Codeigniter is generating this on its own.

```
SELECT * FROM `users` 
WHERE 
    `serial` IS NULL AND 
    `password` IS NULL AND 
    `username` = '[username]' 
LIMIT 1
```

I need Codeigniter to generate this instead as I expected.

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '[username]' LIMIT 1
```

I'm just now starting to code with Codeigniter 3x after using version 2x for the last couple of years. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `$this->db->flush_cache();` and `$this->db->reset_query()` before your query to clear all pre-set elements.

Most likely, `serial` and `pass` have been previously set on `$this->db`.

For more info, check the [CodeIgniter's docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=active%20record#an-example-of-caching)

Comment: I actually just figured this out so I fixed the code that didn't access the DB yet. Thanks.